# When referring to computer coding, would the correct verb spelling (in British English) be "to program" or "to programme"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography

I already know that there are different spellings in British and US English for "programme". Usually, I refer to a computer program with the US spelling as all programming is done in US English, so it only seems appropriate.

But what about the verb? Do you program something or do you programme something in British English?

Comment: Possible source of information: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/get-with-the-programme/

I wish I had time to find something more in depth, but I thought it might help!

Comment: @GnoveltyGnome - That helps a lot. As I suspected, "program" was the correct spelling, but my brain was telling me to spell it the other way. Thanks!

Comment: In the US, I of course see *program* for this.  A few years ago I was surprised to see *programme* used in Canada.  I don't know how wide-spread it is there.

Comment: _all programming is done in US English_ - citation needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In British English, the spelling **program** is used when referring to computer programs, but the spelling **programme** is used for all other purposes.

The following entry is taken from a reputable *British* dictionary<sup>[1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=program&title=21st)</sup>
(I have omitted the entries relating to non-computer meanings for the word):

> **programme** or *(N Amer)* **program
>
> *noun***
> 5. (usually **program**) computing a set of coded instructions to a computer for the performance of a task or a series of operations, written in any of various programming languages.
>
> ***verb*** *(**programmed, programming;** N Amer also **programed, programing**)*
> 3. to set (a computer) by **program** to perform a set of operations.
> 4. to prepare a **program** for a computer.

Note that this *British* dictionary uses the spelling **program** for all uses related to computing.

Comment: Even in North American, the past tense of *to program* is *programmed*.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I had assumed that was the correct version, but my brain was telling me to come on here and check. (Not my fault, blame my brain).

Answer (score 0):

Note, though, that the British dictionary definition states "usually" program.  I'm a British English speaker who's worked as a software developer for many years, and in my experience 99% of British IT workers do indeed spell it "program", but I suppose I'm in the 1% who spells it "programme".  I know of only one colleague (co-worker) who does the same as me.  To my mind, though, there's no reason for a Brit to spell a TV show as "programme" but computer code as "program", other than the requirement that within the coding itself we must use the "American" spelling.

Comment: GeordieG, I wish I could go along with you but in reality, please compare this to billions…

Until about 1960 there was a very clear difference - of 1,000 times - between American and British billions. Today, who would suggest there could be a difference?

What previously mattered a great deal has been reduced to less than 1.000th of what it once meant…

Personally, I'd much prefer that we all used "programme" all of the time and yet, democracy thinks you and I are wrong.